# Downloading/Generating the Flex 3 API spec

Tags: apache-flex, api, download

I have a somewhat unstable internet connection.  I'd like to have the Flex 3 API on my local system for internet down times, but I cant find where it's available for download, or how to generate it.

Does anyone have a link to a downloadable API spec or have instruction on how to generate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to crawl, just unzip: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/flex3_documentation.zip.

Comment: I did not see that link all the way at the bottom. Good eye.

Comment: Actually I followed a link from livedocs, because I remembered seeing it there once before.  Either way, Adobe does a good job with their documentation material up-to-date and connected.

Answer (score 1):

There are download links on this page to various documents: http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/

If you want the Language Reference (and I think that is what you are asking for) which is normally only available as LiveDocs, you'll need to use a website mirroring tool to copy the whole thing to your computer. A tool like HTTrack ( http://www.httrack.com/ ) can help you do that. Just be sure you limit the crawler in HTTrack to only download files with a URL that starts with http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/. Remember that what you will have will be a snapshot of the live docs, so you won't see new comments that get added to it, or revisions made by Adobe unless you download it again later.